# Sending special characters in attached file UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file which is having Japanese character, when i send the mail in shell script the attached mail is having ??? instead of Japanese characters. Any way to fix this?

cat JPData.csv

```
"7","銈炽兗銉撱兗 11 銉°兂銈?銉愩偣銈便儍銉堛儨銉笺儷銈枫儱銉笺偤"
```

Mail script:

```
mail_msg() {   export SUBJECT="Details file""   export
    ATTACH="JPData.csv" (   echo "From: $MAILFROM"
    echo "To: $MAILTO"
    echo "CC: $MAILCC"
    echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
    echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
    echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"'
    echo
    echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
    echo 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'
    echo 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'
    echo
    echo "Please find the attachement"
    echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
    echo 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; name=JPData.csv'
    echo 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'
    echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=JPData.csv'
    echo
    base64 <"$ATTACH"
    echo
    echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--' ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
}
```

Comment: It looks like something has gone wrong with your `export` commands? Shouldn't there be a `;` or a newline before the second one, and *not* one between it and the `ATTACH="JPData.csv"`?

Comment: Did you verify, that your JPData.csv is really UTF-8 encoded? BTW, the text in your file is not Japanese, and some of the characters are not Japanese characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
.
.
.
echo "Please find the attachement"
echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--'
echo '---asdasdasdd'
echo 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8; name=JPData.csv'
echo 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'
echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=JPData.csv'
echo
base64 <"$ATTACH"
echo
echo '---asdasdasdd--' ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
.
.
.
```

?